Node server can't find client-side javascript file. Serves 404 page instead
I am trying to build my first node.js app with express and handlebars. In my homepage(index.hbs) I have a script tag with some client-side JavaScript and works fine:
 <script> console.log("hello there") </script> 

When I try to point to a file though:
 <script src="/public/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

it does not work!
I see the homepage in my browser ok but in the dev tools I get this:
 app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at app.js:1:1)

in the dev tools sources tab I can see that http://localhost:3000/public/js/app.js brings the 404 page.
When I delete the following from my node server to stop all 404 errors:
 app.use('', (req, res) => {
     res.render('404', {})
 })

I get this:
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/public/js/app.js' because its MIME type         ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I don't get any other problems with my public folder it works fine with all css, photographs etc. This is how I point to it:
const pathToPublic = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
app.use(express.static(pathToPublic))

Thanks

What are the contents of public/js/app.js?

The same console.log("Hello there")

@Emmanuel have you accidentally included the script tags <script> and </script> in your app.js file?

@76484, no I haven't, there's only a console.log there to test it, I was planning to add some functionality later...

take a look on this docs express-js-static
since we use express.static we dont need to type /public

It works Carvel! Many thanks, I will read the docs.

Verify MIME type error you saw 'text/html' usually means the server tried to render a 404 error page instead of serving the JavaScript file. This should be resolved once you ensure that:

express.static middleware is set up correctly and is above other route handlers
Inside public dir, you should have a js folder, and within it, a file named app.js (public/js/app.js)
Make sure that app.use(express.static(pathToPublic)) is placed above any route handlers like the 404 route in your server setup. Otherwise, the 404 route could be intercepting requests to static files.


I have everything as you described and even if I remove 404 use altogether, still refuses to read my client-side js file!
